# PublishManager.PublishSmart Deletes an existing item from web db

Tags: publishing

I am using `PublishManager.PublishSmart` to auto publish items from master db to web db.

New items which are in final workflow state are getting published as expected but for the existing items if I make the changes and reset the workflow state other than final, after auto publish runs this existing item gets deleted from web db.

Here is my code

```
Database master = Database.GetDatabase("master");
Database targetDB = Factory.GetDatabase("web");

// passing the rootItemID GUID here
var rootItem = master.GetItem(new ID(rootItemID));

Database[] targets = new Database[1] { targetDB };

Language[] array = rootItem.Languages;

PublishManager.PublishSmart(rootItem.Database, targets, array);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's expected behavior.

In your scenario, you have an item which does not have any version in final workflow state so it's being removed from `web` database while publishing.

When you start editing an item which is already published, a new version of that item should be created.

Then if you execute publish and new version is not ready yet, it will keep existing version of that item published in `web` database. You can still edit new version and finally when it's ready and processed to the final workflow state, it will be published to the `web` database.

And if any further changes are necessary, you create new draft version of that item again.